# I'm getting free() error while using delete [] operator

Tags: c++, heap-corruption, delete-operator

I could not figure out why I got

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006db0e0 ***
```

while trying to free g, u and subset arrays declared inside subs_sum function in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <new>

using namespace std;


int
subs_sum(int n, int * numbers)
{

  int * g = new int [n-1];
  int * u = new int [n-1];
  int * subset = new int [n-1];
  int i, j;
  int sum = 0, nelem = 0;
  int found = 0;

  for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
  {
    g[i] = 0;
    u[i] = 1;
  }

  do
  {

    i = 0;
    j = g[0] + u[0];
    while ((j>=2) || (j<0))
    {
      u[i] = -u[i];
      i++;
      j = g[i] + u[i];
    }

    if (g[i])
    {
      g[i] = 0;
      nelem--;
      sum -= numbers[i];
    }
    else
    {
      g[i] = 1;
      nelem++;
      sum += numbers[i];
    }

    if (g[n-1]) break;

    if (sum == numbers[n-1])
    {

      if (nelem == n-1) // Success!!!
      {
        // Print partial result
        for (int ll=0; ll<=n-2; ll++)
          if (g[ll]) cout << numbers[ll] << "+";
        cout << "\b=" << sum << endl;

        found = 1;

        break;
      }

      if (n-1-nelem >= 2) // Go deeper.
      {

        int pp = 0;

        for (int ll=0; ll<=n-2; ll++)
          if (! g[ll]) subset[pp++] = numbers[ll];

        if (subs_sum(n-1-nelem, subset)) // Match found!!!
        {
          // Print partial result
          for (int ll=0; ll<=n-2; ll++)
            if (g[ll]) cout << numbers[ll] << "+";
          cout << "\b=" << sum << endl;

          found = 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  while(1);

  delete [] g;
  delete [] u;
  delete [] subset;

  return found;
}


int
main(void)
{
  int * numbers;
  int i;

  cin >> i;

  numbers = new int [i];

  for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    cin >> numbers[j];

  cout << "Sorted Numbers: ";

  sort(numbers, numbers+i);

  for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    cout << numbers[j] << " ";
  cout << endl;

  subs_sum(i, numbers);

  delete [] numbers;

  return 0;
}
```

I got no one issue if I comment out

```
delete [] g;
delete [] u;
delete [] subset;
```

and program ran as expected:

```
$ echo -e "11\n1\n41\n10\n24\n5\n12\n6\n14\n9\n35\n7\n" | ./a.out 
Sorted Numbers: 1 5 6 7 9 10 12 14 24 35 41 
1+5=6
9+12+14=35
7+10+24=41
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: If you're confused about why `free()` is being reported when using `delete[]`, it's because `delete[]` often (under the covers) does it's bookkeeping work (calling destructors if needed, etc.), and then delegates to `free()` to do the actual memory release.

Comment: `for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++)` means n-1 + 1 iterations. And the total is `n`. So you need to allocate `n` elements.

Answer (score 2):

you are not making your arrays big enough.  Allocate them as `new int[n]` instead of `new int[n-1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
int * g = new int [n-1];
```

Allocates an array of `n-1` `int`, indices 0 to n-1-1.

Later, you access:

```
for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
  {
    g[i] = 0;
    u[i] = 1;
  }
```

Which is in the last iteration:

```
g[n-1] = 0;
```

Buffer overrun is a common case of undefined behavior, which means anything may happen.

Seems in this case you scrambled the bookkeeping of your allocator, which was actually diagnosed.
Such a happy outcome cannot be guaranteed.

Why does it say `free` found the error, and not `delete`?
Well, the delete-expression under the covers calls the dtor on the object (unless trivial aka no-op as for primitive types) and then the function `operator delete`.
The latter commonly just forwards the request to `free`.